# What is larger for large n: $(n!)^{n^n}$ or $(n^n)!$?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

For large enough n, what is larger: $(n!)^{n^n}$ or $(n^n)!$? I’ve been given this problem in my calculus class and I have no idea how to approach it. All help is welcome.

Comment: If you have questions about class assignments, ask your professor or fellow students. You will be better served by them.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question). Quote from [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): *Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true (you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem), it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Stirling formula, we know $\ln n! = n \ln n - n + O(\ln n)$

Taking logarithm of both expressions, we need to compare $$n^n \cdot \ln n! = n^{n + 1} \ln n - n^{n + 1} + O(n^n \ln n) < n^{n + 1} \ln n - \frac{1}{2} \cdot n^{n + 1}$$ and $$n^n \cdot (\ln n^n) - n^n + O(\ln n^n) = n^{n + 1} \ln n - n^n + O(\ln n^n) > n^{n + 1}\ln n - 2 n^n > n^{n+1}\ln n - \frac{1}{2}\cdot n^{n + 1}$$